# SCP copy from another host if file not found in one host

Tags: bash, scp

I know the name of the file and the host machines on which it could be. I also know that only one of the hosts has that file. So based on this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5455789) I created the following script.

```
if scp "username@host1:/tmp/$1*" ~/$1;
then echo "done";
else scp "username@host2:/tmp/$1*" ~/$1;
fi
```

I have put the above code in a file name `file_copy.sh` and then invoke the file from the terminal as follows `$ ./file_copy.sh filename`, that is where the `$1` argument comes from. I am not sure of the entire file name, but only the prefix in this case, so there is a wild card of `*` but that part can be ignored for this question.

In the above case, I know there are two hosts, and one of them will have my file, so I just do an if else switch, but it feels way too hacky and not elegant enough.

Question:

1. Is there a better solution to if then else above to doing the SCP?
2. In both the if and else branch I use SCP, which requires me to type the password twice. On both the hosts, the user name and password are the same. Is there any way, in the shell file, that I do not have to enter the password again on the terminal.
3. The above case has two hosts, but if I have n hosts and a similar situation. That is one file, in one host, but not sure which one, but all hosts have the same user name and password credentials. How the above script can be generalized. Is there a way to make a switch case in shell script.

Thanks

Comment: This might help: [How To Use SSHFS to Mount Remote File Systems Over SSH](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if rsync command ran successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454391/check-if-rsync-command-ran-successful)

Comment: Taking a step back, why don't you know which host will have the file? Can whatever process creates the file simply push it to a fixed, known location?

Comment: I would also *strongly* consider setting up public-key authentication so that you don't need to enter a password at all.

Comment: @chepner the boxes process a request to create file, based on whom load balancer has selected. Which is why I know one of them but not which one. Also, the boxes can only be accessed over VPN, but still needs another password.

Comment: The process should work with the load balancer. Whether `host1` or `host2` creates the file, the process should ensure that it becomes available on (arbitrarily picking one host) `host1`, so that you don't have to worry about the details of the load-balancing environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could use `rsync` instead. `rsync -r -z -c` will return [better error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454391/check-if-rsync-command-ran-successful).
2. You could use `sshpass` to automatically enter a password

Then you could..

```
if sshpass PA55WORD rsync -r -z -c "username@host1:/tmp/$1*" ~/$1;
then echo "done";
else sshpass PASSWORD rsync -r -z -c "username@host2:/tmp/$1*" ~/$1;
fi
```

I would personally recommend against typing a password in plain text. [ssh private keys](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-use-ssh-public-key-authentication/) are useful for this exact problem. You could use `sshpass -f FILE_PATH` or some other clever encryption method of getting the password in, but `sshpass` is your friend here.

3. For multiple hosts, all with the same username and password:

```
HOSTS=( "host1" "host2" "host3" )

for H in ${HOSTS[@]}
do
  sshpass -p PASSWORD rsync -r -z -c "username@${H}:/tmp/$1*" ~/$1 && break
done
```

For multiple hosts, all with different usernames and passwords

```
HOSTS=( "host1" "host2" "host3" )
USERS=( "user1" "user2" "user3" )
PASSS=( "pass1" "pass2" "pass3" )

for i in ${!HOSTS[@]}
do
  sshpass -p ${PASSS[$i]} rsync -r -z -c "${USERS[$i]}@${HOSTS[$i]}:/tmp/$1*" ~/$1 && break
done
```

Comment: I went for the second code snippet, without sshpass, looks like I can live with entering password multiple times.